# How to change a string type?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to enter a string.

```
string value;
cin >> value;
```

And i want to take the string and change parts of a string in to integers.

eg. 00: Input 22
I want to change "00"(without ":") in to an integer. Keep "Input" a a string and make the last two character to integers.

Now i want to take the parts that i have changed and display the in a array. One col for each part of the converted string.

Comment: parse string... it's very simple.

Comment: I know that is why is tipped it.

Comment: Just search a little in so, This has been answered a hundred times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - [To return a substring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

2 - [To Convert a String to int](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)